# Solo dice game (from Reiner Knizia’s Decathlon)

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, dice

I'm trying to implement [Reiner Knizia’s Decathlon](https://knizia.de/wp-content/uploads/reiner/pdfs/Knizia-Website-Decathlon.pdf), a set of 10 solo dice games played with 8 dices named after Decathlon events in Olympics.

The first event is called "100 Metres".
The player divides 8 dices into two sets of 4, then pick a set and throw.
He may keep the dice (freeze) or rethrow. After he is satisfied with the result, he does the same with the other set. He has a total of 5 rethrows. The score is the total of the dice after he freezes all dice.

My approach:
There are 10 events, so it is going to be a lot of repetitive code. I made a Event class, and each Event will have a self.state dict object keeping tracking of dice rolls and number of rethrows. Each event will also have a self.print_game_state object.

Here is the code. Any idea to write this code smarter?

common.py

```
import random


class DiceRoller:

    def __new__(cls, num_dice=1):
        return [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice)]


class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'state'):
            self.state = dict()

    def print_game_state(self):
        for key, value in self.state.items():
            print(f'{key}: {value}')
        print(f'Score: {self.score()}')
        if self.game_finished():
            print('Game Finished')
```

e100metres.py

```
from common import DiceRoller, Event


class E100Metres(Event):
    '''100 metres event.'''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.state.update({
            'frozen_sets': 0,
            'remaining_rerolls': 5,
            'frozen_dices': [],
            'current_rolls': DiceRoller(4)
        })
        self.print_game_state()

    def game_finished(self):
        return self.state['frozen_sets'] >= 2

    def no_more_rerolls(self):
        return self.state['remaining_rerolls'] <= 0

    def reroll(self):
        if self.game_finished():
            raise Exception('Game already finished')
        if self.no_more_rerolls():
            raise Exception('No more rerolls')
        self.state['remaining_rerolls'] -= 1
        self.state['current_rolls'] = DiceRoller(4)
        self.print_game_state()

    def freeze(self):
        if self.game_finished():
            raise Exception('Game already finished')
        self.state['frozen_dices'] += self.state['current_rolls']
        self.state['frozen_sets'] += 1
        if self.game_finished():
            self.state['current_rolls'] = list()
        else:
            self.state['current_rolls'] = DiceRoller(4)
        self.print_game_state()

    def score(self):
        return sum(self.state['frozen_dices'])
```

Comment: Please verify your code. The braces don't match.

Comment: Is there some code missing? I can't see how you use `E100Metres`, and for example nothing ever changes `frozen_sets` from its initial value of `0`.

Comment: Code fixed. To play I'll initiate an `E100Metres` object, then call the functions `freeze` or `reroll` directly.